# Null-reference exception - "Co-variant array conversion from string[] to to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation"

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, covariance

I have a bit of trouble getting a command right. I have a dictionary, `Dictionary<string, Delegate>()`, and I'm trying to add delegates to parse strings entered into Console.

Example of command:

```
AdminCommands.Add(":activate", new Action<string>(id => stregsystem.GetProductByID(int.Parse(id)).Active = true));
```

I always get a NullReferenceException, but I'm having a hard time understanding why.
I get this warning,

> Co-variant array conversion from string[] to to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation.

```
private void ParseCommand(string command)
{
    string[] input = command.Split();

    if (command[0] == ':')
    {
        AdminCommands[input[0]]?.DynamicInvoke(input.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
....
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If `AdminCommands` or`command` is null, you will get the exception. The warning has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The warning is telling you that if DynamicInvoke tries to write a giraffe into the array of objects you're giving it, that will fail because that array of objects is actually an array of strings. But first, DynamicInvoke does not write, and second, if it did, you'd get a type conversion error, not a null dereference error.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the warning you can say `input.Skip(1).Cast<object>().ToArray()`

Comment: As knittl says, something here is null. Could be AdminCommands, could be command, could be stregsystem, could be the value returned by GetValueById, could be something you haven't told us about.  Use a debugger, find out what it is.

Comment: you might be able to [Use the debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) to figure out what here is null

Comment: @EricLippert Since `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T`, one can eliminate the warning a bit more elegantly with `input.Skip(1).ToArray<object>();`. The `IEnumerable<string>` we have __"is an"__ `IEnumerable<object>` because of the covariance.

Comment: Nice! Good suggestion.